# How can I reset my GRUB background to default?

Tags: grub2, default, debian, desktop-background

I installed some sort of software (I think it had to do with Gnome) that changed the splash image behind the GRUB boot interface from the standard purple background to a somewhat tacky Debian splash image.

Is there any sort of quick set of commands I can enter or file I can delete to change it back to the default background?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A quick way** to delete the file is done opening a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and executing these command

```
sudo rm /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

### Insight on that file

It comes from the `desktop-base` package. That package's function as described in control file is

> This package contains various miscellaneous files which are used by
> Debian Desktop installations.  Currently, it provides some
> Debian-related artwork and themes, .desktop files containing links to
> Debian related material (suitable for placement on a user's desktop),
> and other common files between the available desktop environments
> such as GNOME and KDE.

It includes various wallpapers for both GNOME and EDE, splash screens etc.

### If you don't want that package

You can remove the package by this command

```
sudo apt-get purge desktop-base
```

then executes these commands to restore default grub screen

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

### If you want to keep the splash files and want the default grub background

In that case, use the below command to disable checking for grub background file

```
 sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
```

and then execute

```
sudo update-initramfs -u 
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: It worked, for the most part. It got rid of the Debian wallpaper, although now it has a black background as opposed to the purple one, and after selection the screen stays dark until Ubuntu is finished loading (as opposed to showing the logo and the progress bar). But those are minor, and it is still preferable to that splash image. Is there any way I can manually choose which theme in the /grub.d/ folder to apply? Either way, thanks.

Comment: @AlexBixel glad that it helps. I have updated the info. you should run `sudo update-initramfs -u` after removing the file. thanks

Answer (score 10):

A simple way without deleting files or changing file mode bits is:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and insert

```
GRUB_BACKGROUND=""
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Not sure why this gets downvoted, but it's actually the better answer.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the option I was looking for to easily avoid unlocking my encrypted root device.

Comment: Side note for people encrypting /root - it also works to place the background png in /boot/grub, and update-grub. This also avoids having to unlock /root at that stage.