# Ubuntu 12.04 shows Debian grub menu!

Tags: grub2, xfce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reset my GRUB background to default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160244/how-can-i-reset-my-grub-background-to-default)

I installed xfce4 by using "sudo apt-get install xfce4", and I decided I didn't like xfce4 so I purged all of the xfce4 utils, now I get my grub menu shown as the Debian grub menu, but I would like it to go back to the original Ubuntu 12.04 one. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu is a Debian distro, it's kind of expected to behave as Debian, is it not?

Comment: Reinstalling Grub would be good option.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the background image, not to the actual (textual) content of the grub screen. The default 12.04 grub background is a simple purple whereas the "Debian" one is more "picturesque".